# How to stop masking on svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Ok, I have an svg I created in illustrator and opened in an editor so I could get the path. I then applied a filter:

```css
#center {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

#inner {
  width: 400px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.4s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.4s;
  overflow: visible;
}

#center #svgContainer {
  perspective: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="svgContainer">
  <div id="inner">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <filter id="Blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="19" /></filter>
      <g id="Img"><path class="cls-1" d="M9.5,204.08q26.14-10,51.48-22,24.65-11.67,48.32-25.21,11.83-6.78,23.39-14c8.05-5,20.78-11.32,17.8-23-1.5-5.85-6.76-8.72-11.92-10.78-4.25-1.7-8.54-3.3-12.84-4.86q-13.14-4.74-26.54-8.69A490.14,490.14,0,0,0,44.6,83.09a22.13,22.13,0,0,1-4.66-1.25l1.79.76A12.55,12.55,0,0,1,40.56,82c-.28-.16-1.46-1-.27-.11s.12,0-.12-.24c.84,1.15,1.06,1.41.65.79a5.28,5.28,0,0,1-.27-.53l.75,1.79a7.3,7.3,0,0,1-.37-1.29l.27,2a7.1,7.1,0,0,1,0-1.22l-.27,2a8.33,8.33,0,0,1,.54-2L40.69,85a14,14,0,0,1,1.05-1.85c.55-.87-.32.27-.4.48a4.14,4.14,0,0,1,.68-.79c.8-.89,1.65-1.75,2.52-2.57s1.79-1.57,2.71-2.33c.65-.53-1.6,1.2-.47.38l.6-.45c.51-.36,1-.72,1.54-1.07a76.74,76.74,0,0,1,12.77-6.67l-1.79.76c8.91-3.76,18.29-6.5,27-10.77A17.82,17.82,0,0,0,94,53.87a11.27,11.27,0,0,0,.09-11.74c-1.71-2.82-4.56-4.46-7.27-6.17-2.11-1.34-4.19-2.73-6.2-4.23-.38-.28-1-.89.53.42-.31-.27-.64-.52-1-.78q-.8-.66-1.56-1.35a37.89,37.89,0,0,1-2.89-2.92l-.53-.63c-.19-.22-1-1.21-.19-.2s0-.05-.14-.23-.39-.57-.58-.86a23.21,23.21,0,0,1-1.83-3.45l.76,1.8A23.43,23.43,0,0,1,71.7,17.8l.27,2a19.79,19.79,0,0,1,0-5.1l-.27,2a17.15,17.15,0,0,1,1-3.79L72,14.68a14,14,0,0,1,.79-1.6c.34-.58,1.61-2.22.06-.27A8.13,8.13,0,0,0,75,7.51a7.66,7.66,0,0,0-2.2-5.31A7.54,7.54,0,0,0,67.54,0c-1.86.08-4.09.67-5.3,2.19a25.09,25.09,0,0,0-4,6.7,23.1,23.1,0,0,0-1.35,6.15,25.58,25.58,0,0,0,1.34,11.07c2.89,8.33,9,14.38,16,19.43,1.63,1.18,3.32,2.28,5,3.36.78.5,1.58,1,2.36,1.48a3.78,3.78,0,0,0,.6.41c-.18,0-1.36-1.22-.69-.5.12.12.24.26.37.37.52.47-1.07-1.61-.49-.52l-.76-1.79a4.85,4.85,0,0,1,.31,1l-.27-2a4.39,4.39,0,0,1,0,1l.27-2a5.9,5.9,0,0,1-.23.92l.75-1.79c-.17.4-.44.75-.63,1.15.67-1.42.92-1.12.25-.47l-.55.49c1-.74,1.25-1,.78-.61s-.72.48-1.1.7a42.55,42.55,0,0,1-4.8,2.22l1.79-.76c-9.76,4.09-19.95,7.15-29.4,12a61.8,61.8,0,0,0-13.38,9.09,31.65,31.65,0,0,0-6.17,7.15,13.68,13.68,0,0,0-.73,13.18c2.76,5.73,9.35,7.41,15.05,8.38q9.11,1.55,18.14,3.46,18.06,3.83,35.78,9.1a380,380,0,0,1,39,13.54l-1.79-.75a24.46,24.46,0,0,1,3,1.59c.7.41-1.25-1.11-.7-.54.19.2.4.4.61.59.77.72-.66-.7-.56-.73a5,5,0,0,1,.46.89l-.76-1.8a6.36,6.36,0,0,1,.34,1.35l-.27-2a6.1,6.1,0,0,1,0,1.35l.27-2a8,8,0,0,1-.37,1.29l.76-1.79a11,11,0,0,1-.56,1.08c0,.06-.31.37-.3.44s1.09-1.29.62-.8c-.67.69-1.32,1.34-2,2-.95.83,1.34-1,.31-.24l-1.08.73-2.88,1.85q-5.36,3.4-10.77,6.73-10.92,6.71-22.1,13-22.23,12.53-45.34,23.42Q39.3,175.79,26,181.41l1.79-.76q-11.07,4.66-22.29,9A8.16,8.16,0,0,0,1,193.06a7.68,7.68,0,0,0-.76,5.78c1.16,3.56,5.31,6.74,9.23,5.24Z"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    <use style="fill:pink;" filter="url(#Blur)" xlink:href="#Img"
      transform="translate(0,0)"/>
    <use style="fill:white;" xlink:href="#Img"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is great, except even with overflow:visible and changing div sizes, I get a masked svg:

[image]

What is wrong here?
updated:

```
<svg svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -70 800 1081">
```

Comment: What is the result you're wanting? Looks like your SVG is missing a `viewBox` attribute and has no explicit width or height specified.

Can you post in the exact SVG code you get when you export from Illustrator?

Comment: @DonkeyShame great catch - see the edit above. Found the viewbox and tried making it bigger, solved the problem somewhat but you can still see cutoff on the gaussian blur. Why does upping the last 2 values not have any further effect?

Comment: You need to set the height and width of your filter too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is that your SVG is falling out the bottom of its container.

You'll want to export your SVG in a way that ensures this doesn't happen. One way to tackle this is with the `viewBox` attribute (see [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/svg-viewport-and-viewbox-for-beginners--cms-30844)).

> viewBox = {min-x} {min-y} {width} {height}

In my hastily-contructed example file below, you'll see that my SVG's `viewBox` attribute is set to `"0 0 417 376"`. Its width and height are set to the same dimensions, respectively.

As to why tweaking the 3rd and 4th numbers isn't getting the result you want, well...

> The ‘viewBox’ attribute specifies a rectangle in user space which should be mapped to the bounds of the viewport established by the given element.

Quoted from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)

In other words, as I understand it, the viewport established by your given element is too small to accommodate the spread of the blur; no matter how large you make the `viewBox`, it's still mapping that rectangular space into the size constraints of the parent element.

Or, perhaps something else...?  Who knows.

At any rate, you'll want to accommodate that blur radius inside the SVG you export from Illustrator. To do that, place the guts of your graphic inside a rectangle that is large enough to encapsulate the graphic and its blur spread. Remove the stroke/fill of that encapsulating rectangle and group the whole mess together. Export that group as an SVG.

I don't use Illustrator any more but something like that should get you going. Illustrator may have options you can tweak with regard the `viewBox` attribute, so watch for that when you're exporting.

Good luck!

**Pro-tip:** It doesn't matter how large your graphic is since it's vector based. You could export it at could 100px by 100px and that would be fine. You could subsequently control its display size by setting its width and height explicitly (or by sizing the SVG with CSS, or whatever).

Some good stuff here: 
[Perplexed by SVG viewBox, width, height, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553392/perplexed-by-svg-viewbox-width-height-etc)

```html
<div id="svgContainer">
  <div id="inner">
    <svg width="417" height="376" viewBox="0 0 417 376" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g filter="url(#filter0_df)">
        <path d="M198.5 70C193.667 77.8333 193.4 89 205 101C216.6 113 224.5 116.5 223.5 122.5C222.5 128.5 169.148 137.338 156 164.5C150.675 175.5 309 198.947 291 217C273 235.053 215.166 273.072 126 305.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" />
      </g>
      <path d="M198.5 70C193.667 77.8333 193.4 89 205 101C216.6 113 224.5 116.5 223.5 122.5C222.5 128.5 169.148 137.338 156 164.5C150.675 175.5 309 198.947 291 217C273 235.053 215.166 273.072 126 305.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" />
      <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_df" x="67.9971" y="11.9986" width="282.433" height="351.504" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" />
          <feOffset />
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="24" />
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0" />
          <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow" />
          <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape" />
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" result="effect2_foregroundBlur" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```